# OpenERP 7 : How can I make a button inserting a predefined text in the Clipboard?

Tags: python, odoo, clipboard

I am new to OpenERP and Python and here is my problem :

In a form view the user can see the address of one of his customer, my mission is to add a button which, when the user clicks on it, saves the address in the clipboard so the user only has to paste it where he wants to, instead of selecting the text and make the short cut key to copy it.

This is the last thing I've tried, I was a bit lost with the many different answers people gave on Internet and I'm not very comfortable with functions yet :

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm
import sys
import gtk
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')


class address_copy(orm.Model):

    _inherit = "res.partner"

    def address_copy(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        address = partner.street + '\n' + partner.zip + ' ' + partner.city + '\n' + partner.country_id + ', ' + partner.state_id
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(address)
```

There isn't any problem when I update my database with this module, but when I click on the button I've created, I have this error :

```
2015-05-01 15:45:12,305 20229 ERROR Armand openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
  res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/addons/7.0/purchase/partner.py", line 44, in copy
  return super(res_partner, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default=default, context=context)
TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
2015-05-01 15:45:12,305 20229 ERROR Armand openerp.netsvc: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
  result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  res = fn(db, uid, *params)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
  res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/addons/7.0/purchase/partner.py", line 44, in copy
  return super(res_partner, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default=default, context=context)
TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

So it looks like the problem comes from this copy function in partner.py, although my class inherits this module, I didn't change anything in it and I don't really know how it works.
Here is the copy function in partner.py :

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
        if default is None:
            default = {}

        default.update({'purchase_order_ids': []})

    return super(res_partner, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default=default, context=context)

    _columns = {
        'property_product_pricelist_purchase': fields.property('product.pricelist', type='many2one', relation='product.pricelist', domain=[('type','=','purchase')], string="Purchase Pricelist", view_load=True, help="This pricelist will be used, instead of the default one, for purchases from the current partner"),
        'purchase_order_count': fields.function(_purchase_order_count, string='# of Purchase Order', type='integer'),
        'purchase_order_ids': fields.one2many('purchase.order','partner_id','Purchase Order')
    }
res_partner()
```

Do you have any idea of how can I make it works ? My function may be wrong too. Thanks in advance for all people who will try to help me ! If it is too complicated, maybe a button which only selects the text so the user can copy it directly could do as well.

EDIT : If I try to launch it from the sale module of OpenERP, with a simple button and a function "pyperclip.copy("string"), I get this error :

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
  action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
  return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
  result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
  raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/odoo/web/7.0/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
  return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
  result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  res = fn(db, uid, *params)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
  res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
 File "/home/odoo/personnal_addons/sale_option/sale_option.py", line 664, in copy
  return super(sale_order, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
 File "/home/odoo/addons/7.0/sale_stock/sale_stock.py", line 49, in copy
  return super(sale_order, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
 File "/home/odoo/addons/7.0/sale/sale.py", line 87, in copy
  return super(sale_order, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 5126, in copy
  data = self.copy_data(cr, uid, id, default, context)
 File "/home/odoo/addons/7.0/mail/mail_thread.py", line 326, in copy_data
  return super(mail_thread, self).copy_data(cr, uid, id, default=default, context=context)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 5023, in copy_data
  data = self.read(cr, uid, [id], fields_to_copy.keys(), context=context)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3679, in read
  result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3730, in _read_flat for sub_ids in cr.split_for_in_conditions(ids):
 File "/home/odoo/server/7.0/openerp/sql_db.py", line 258, in split_for_in_conditions
  return tools.misc.split_every(self.IN_MAX, set(ids))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code. So it is not easy to find the issue until you clear the most.

In this code,

```
address = partner.street + '\n' + partner.zip + ' ' + partner.city + '\n' + partner.country_id + ', ' + partner.state_id
```

you don't have a `partner` object to get the address details.

And then in this code,

`partner.country_id` and `partner.state_id` you will get a object. So you need use `partner.country_id.name` or whatever field you need.

And then in this code, i hope you are trying to use the `tkinter` module to perform the clipboard operation.

```
self.clipboard_clear()
self.clipboard_append(address)
```

For this you need a object from the `tkinter` class. It is a cross platform GUI library. Try this

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm
from Tkinter import Tk

class address_copy(orm.Model):

    _inherit = "res.partner"

    def address_copy(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        for partner in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            r = Tk()
            address = str(partner.street) + '\n' + str(partner.zip) + ' ' + str(partner.city) + '\n' + str(partner.country_id.name) + ', ' + str(partner.state_id.name)
            r.withdraw()
            r.clipboard_clear()
            r.clipboard_append(address)
            r.destroy()
```

In python3, `from Tkinter import Tk` should be `from tkinter import Tk`. Since Odoo uses python2.x above won't be a problem.

Or you can use [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) module. It will work fine with minimal code.

Simple example:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
spam = pyperclip.paste()
print spam
```

For your case:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm
import pyperclip

class address_copy(orm.Model):

    _inherit = "res.partner"

    def address_copy(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        for partner in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            address = str(partner.street) + '\n' + str(partner.zip) + ' ' + str(partner.city) + '\n' + str(partner.country_id.name) + ', ' + str(partner.state_id.name)
            pyperclip.copy(address)
```

I personally prefer the last method.

Comment: I feel a bit dumb with all these errors in my code, I work with the "learning by doing" style and so I am stuck by almost everything...
In any case, the Pyperclip module seems to work, I don't get errors but the text isn't copied in the clipboard, I think it is due to the mess in the OpenERP modules that have been created by others people before me so the import is certainly wrong, but I'll try to handle it.
Thank you a lot for your help, I really appreciate the way you're answering my questions and explaining where the errors come from all at once !

Comment: Hello again, so recently I've tried to fix my module but it seems that the problem doesn't come from import, or at least there is another problem, if I just pass a string to address (like "Hello World!"), I don't have it in the clipboard, but it works in a short script outside of OpenERP, so I wonder if this module may in some way copy address in the server side and not in the clipboard of the client side. So I don't know what to do about this.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with openerp or server side. If the simple example using pyperclip in the post is working in another script means, it should work in the openerp also. Try if you're passing more than one partner or the partner has address. If you're sure about the single instance of the patner always come to your method means, you can remove the for loop. Try to use this hardcoded value to debug.

`def address_copy(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):`
`pyperclip.copy("address")`

Comment: For now I'm just trying to run this module when I ask it to copy a simple string, not a partner reference or whatever, and even a simple pyperclip.copy("random string") doesn't work on OpenERP when it works fine in a Python script outside OpenERP.

Comment: I have tested with 2 different versions of openerp code. Its working fine. Try this in base modules such as sale etc... to make sure the error is not in custom module.
`import pyperclip`
`pyperclip.copy("The text to be copied to the clipboard.")`
`spam = pyperclip.paste()`
`print spam`

Comment: I've edited my question with the error I get when I try what you said in your last comment.